# spring rest docs - folding long jsons

Tags: spring, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

Is there a way to show only some sections of long json (req/resp) and hide others? We want to show some changes in specific field/section without whole noise of complete json. 
There are highlighters, which make highlighting on client side, maybe some folding can be also configured?

Comment: you can track through key and select value from specific kay and present it?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads-subsections

Comment: this not exactly what I want, but thanks, maybe I'll use it.